# Helper para escrever HtmlHelpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, microsoft-help-viewer

Estou tentando escrever um *HtmlHelper* e vendo alguns exemplos básicos achei um com a classe `TagBuilder` que já **[ajuda](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/720515/Custom-HTML-Helper-for-MVC-Application)**:

```cs
namespace MyNamespace 
{  
    public static class MyHeleprs
    { 
        public static MvcHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
        string source, string alternativeText)
        {
            //declare the html helper 
            var builder = new TagBuilder("image"); 
            //hook the properties and add any required logic
            builder.MergeAttribute("src", source);
            builder.MergeAttribute("alt", alternativeText);
            //create the helper with a self closing capability
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
        } 
    } 
}
```

Só que eu desejo criar um facilitador maior, para no fim manipular um valor que vai ser exibido, algumas classes `css` etc. Logo, não gostaria de ter que reescrever todo um `helper` que já existe como o `TextBoxFor` ou o `EditorFor`.

Partindo dessa vontade, então pensei em poder reaproveitar esses helpers e adicionar minhas manipulações.

Estava pensando em fazer o seguinte:

```cs
public static MvcHtmlString FieldFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
    string cssClass = "",
    bool placeHolder = false,
    bool autoFocus = false,
    object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    var builder = new TagBuilder(
        htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes).ToString());

    // value attribute
    ...
    builder.Attributes["type"] = "text";
    builder.Attributes["value"] = value;           

    // autofocus
    if (autoFocus)
        builder.Attributes.Add("autofocus", "autofocus");

    // css
    builder.AddCssClass(cssClass);

    // placeholder
    ...
    return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
}
```

Enfim, destacando o que eu pensei:

```cs
var builder = new TagBuilder(htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes).ToString());
```

Mas o `TagBuilder` não funciona assim.

Manipular algo já pronto ajuda por não ter que ficar reescrevendo coisas que o framework já faz, como gerar a Id e o Name do elemento entre outros.

**Como posso resolver isso? Qual seria um caminho mais prático?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Exemplo:***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public static class Methods
    {
        public static String ControllerName(this HtmlHelper HtmlHelper)
        {
            return HtmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        }
        public static String ControllerName(this AjaxHelper AjaxHelper)
        {
            return AjaxHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        }
        public static String ActionName(this HtmlHelper HtmlHelper)
        {
            return HtmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        }
        public static String ActionName(this AjaxHelper AjaxHelper)
        {
            return AjaxHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        }
        public static IHtmlString FieldFor<TModel, TProperty>(
            this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
            Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
            string cssClass = "",
            string placeHolder = "",
            bool autoFocus = false,
            object htmlAttributes = null)
        {
            IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributesList = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            if (htmlAttributes != null)
            {
                foreach (PropertyInfo prop in htmlAttributes.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    htmlAttributesList.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(htmlAttributes));
                }
            }            
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cssClass))
            {
                htmlAttributesList.Add("css", cssClass);
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(placeHolder))
            {
                htmlAttributesList.Add("placeholder", placeHolder);
            }
            if (autoFocus)
            {
                htmlAttributesList.Add("autofocus", "autofocus");
            }            
            return new MvcHtmlString(htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributesList).ToHtmlString());
        }      
    }
}
```

<sup>**Obs: Existem além do que você tinha alguns métodos a mais que geralmente eu uso para montar alguma coisa padrão, mas, a sua dúvida seria assim a maneira de se fazer, sem a `TagBuilder`.**</sup>

***Como usar:***

```
@Html.FieldFor(a => a.Nome);
@Html.FieldFor(a => a.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { id="Nome" })
@Html.FieldFor(a => a.Nome, cssClass: "", placeHolder: "", autoFocus: false, htmlAttributes: null)
@Html.FieldFor(a => a.Nome, "form-control", "Digite o seu nome", true, null)
```

Comment: Só lembrando que esse código ta testado e funcionou pelo menos nos meus testes não sei se passou algo qualquer coisa mantenha informado... vlw @TiagoSilva